# How to embed imgur videos into markdown documents?

Tags: markdown, imgur

This is something I do everyday for images, but today I needed to use a video in place, for some reason I cant seem to get it to work.
I uploaded a `test.mp4` file to [Imgur](https://imgur.com). The file gets displayed on that page and I can get share links, which are:

```
https://imgur.com/94hXYDX
[img]https://i.imgur.com/94hXYDX.mp4[/img]
[Imgur](https://imgur.com/94hXYDX)
```

But if I attempt to embed these links into a markdown document file in Obsidian the video is not displayed, I have tried the following:

```
![](https://imgur.com/94hXYDX)
![](https://i.imgur.com/94hXYDX.mp4)
```

I also tried the markdown preview of Stack Exchange websites and some other forums. The file will simply not display on that page.

I also tried uploading the file on another website and sharing it from there:

```
https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/my2pcppokb7.mp4

![](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/my2pcppokb7.mp4)
[img]https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/my2pcppokb7.mp4[/img]
```

Again same issue, will not display. Am I missing somethign here??

Comment: Some SE sites can embed such as youtube video - https://movies.stackexchange.com/ is one, using just the link, no markdown, eg `https://youtube.com/abc123` - but can't embed mp4 etc video from imgur. All sites can embed imgur GIF though.

Comment: To note, ***into markdown documents*** is a way to vague thing. Every platform/system can have different functionality built-in, and different implementations of Markdown. It would be helpful if you specify what system that is on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

**Markdown** doesn't have an option for video embedding/preview. See the full Markdown Syntex info from its creator https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img.

As an alternative, you can either [convert the video to GIF](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif) (if it's short enough), or embed a thumbnail image of the video and hyperlink it to the video.

Comment: Damn this was painfull. I thank you for letting me in on this secret. I have been making do with `.gif` but its a highly volatile format and not suited for long format video. This is mostly for sharing information on forums that supports bbcode or more recent site that support Markdown format. Is there really no way to imbed video in posts? I will keep looking though. Thanks.